# recursive descent parser

Tags: parsing, go

Here is a non-predictive recursive descent parser I wrote for the following grammar:

```
E : E1 '*' E
  | E1 '/' E
  | E1 '+' E
  | E1 '-' E
  | E1
  ;

E1 : NUM
   | '(' E ')'
   ;
```

It can be run against the token stream

```
func main() {
    // (m) * (m / (m))
    valid := Parse([]Token{
        {Value: "("},
        {Type: T_NUM},
        {Value: ")"},
        {Value: "*"},
        {Value: "("},
        {Type: T_NUM},
        {Value: "/"},
        {Value: "("},
        {Type: T_NUM},
        {Value: ")"},
        {Value: ")"},
    })  

    println(valid)
}
```

It doesn't build an AST, it simply validates a token stream against the language.

```
// an enumeration of named token types. for
// this language, there is only one named
// token type (the number). all other token
// types are referred to by their string value
const (
    _ = iota
    T_NUM
)

// a token type refers to the terminal class of the
// token (eg T_NUM), whereas the value refers to
// its textual representation (eg "23")
type Token struct {
    Type  int
    Value string
}

// a slice of tokens that represents the input stack.
// the base pointer is passed to the production func
// that is matching against the stack.
type TokenStack []Token

// type definition for a production. given a stack and
// a base pointer, return the position at which the
// production ends. if no production is
// matched return NoMatch, or -1.
type Production func(TokenStack, int) int

// returned by a production func if no match  is found
// on the token stack at a given base pointer
const NoMatch = -1

// will return true if a given stack is valid for the
// language. a parse is valid when the return value from
// a production equals the length of the input stack
// (meaning the entire stack matches the production)
func Parse(s TokenStack) bool {
    p := E(s, 0)
    return M(p) && p == len(s)
}

// a production func for the rule:
//
//  E : E1 '*' E
//    | E1 '/' E
//    | E1 '+' E
//    | E1 '-' E
//    | E1
//    ;
func E(s TokenStack, p int) int {
    if p1 := Consecutive(s, p, E1, V("*"), E); M(p1) {
        return p1
    } else if p1 := Consecutive(s, p, E1, V("/"), E); M(p1) {
        return p1
    } else if p1 := Consecutive(s, p, E1, V("+"), E); M(p1) {
        return p1
    } else if p1 := Consecutive(s, p, E1, V("-"), E); M(p1) {
        return p1
    } else if p1 = E1(s, p); M(p1) {
        return p1
    }
    return NoMatch
}

// a production func for the rule:
//
//  E1 : T_NUM
//     | '(' E ')'
//     ;
func E1(s TokenStack, p int) int {
    if p1 := T(T_NUM)(s, p); M(p1) {
        return p1
    } else if p1 = Consecutive(s, p, V("("), E, V(")")); M(p1) {
        return p1
    }
    return NoMatch
}

// will try to match consecutive productions against
// a token stack, keeping track of the length of each
// match. if every consecutive rule matches, return
// the length of every match added to the base pointer
// originally passed to this function
func Consecutive(s TokenStack, p int, rules ...Production) int {
    var match_len = 0
    for _, rulei := range rules {
        if p1 := rulei(s, p+match_len); M(p1) {
            match_len += p1 - (p + match_len)
        } else {
            return NoMatch
        }
    }
    return p + match_len
}

// return a production func that will
// match a given token value
func V(v string) Production {
    return func(s TokenStack, p int) int {
        if len(s) > p && string(s[p].Value) == v {
            return p + 1
        }
        return NoMatch
    }
}

// return a production func that will
// match a given token type
func T(t int) Production {
    return func(s TokenStack, p int) int {
        if len(s) > p && s[p].Type == t {
            return p + 1
        }
        return NoMatch
    }
}

// a function to conveniently check the
// return value of a production for a match
func M(p int) bool {
    return p > NoMatch
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Go fmt

First off, always `go fmt` your source code. The best thing about Go is that it always looks the same.

### Godoc

Follow the godoc standard for comments. When commenting a function, start with the function name, capitalized, and end with a dot. Use proper grammar (like capital letter after punctuation). This makes [automatically generated documentation](https://godoc.org/sort#Sort) look great, and further normalizes [how Go code looks](https://golang.org/src/sort/sort.go#L218). `TokenStack represents the input stack.` is a good first sentance to start with.

(Actually, maybe `TokenStack` should be named `InputStack`, if that's what it really is?)

### Const

Using `iota` to assign a single value like you are doing looks wierd. It's not that clear what you are doing.

```
const T_NUM = 1
```

or

```
const T_NUM = iota+1
```

or actually use the first value; make the nil value useful:

```
const (
    T_UNKNOWN = iota
    T_NUM
)
```

Usually, there is more than one constant. Since you're only using one, I'm wondering if it would be better to remove it as well. Every valid token is T_NUM, after all, so why have a constant for it in the first place?

### Type

If you are going to use T_NUM as an enum, give it a type. Right now, `T_NUM` is just a constant integer. That means we can do weird things like `T_NUM + T_NUM * 5`. If we define a new type, such as `type TokenType int` and then make `T_NUM` a constant `TokenType` instead, we get a compililation error, since multiplying a `TokenType` by a number doesn't make sense. In many C-like languages, like C and C++, defining a new type like this wouldn't help, but in Go, types are real types, not type aliases.

### Package main

You're starting the file with `package main` but there's no `func main()` in the source code. It looks like this is a library package, and in that case, the package name should be changed. The Go Blog has a great post about [naming packages and things in packages](https://blog.golang.org/package-names).

### NoMatch

It feels like `NoMatch` should be an `error` (for example `var NoMatch = errors.New("could not match TokenStack to known rules"). Right now it looks like C-code.

### Exporting everything

Everything in your package is exported. You probably want some of the functions or types to be package-local. I'd aim for only exporting a single function: `Parse`. That way, it's super simple for someone to get started with the package. `V` and `T` should definitely not be exported as they stand, but if they have to be exported, they should probably be renamed.

Package `testing` only gets away with exporting `T` because that's almost the only thing it's exporting, and everytime you use it, you write `testing.T`. The name of the package helps explain what `T` is.

### In-bound errors

Some of your functions return `NoMatch` on error, which is just `-1`. This is a common way of doing things in C or C++, but not in Go. It's usually better to return multiple values, the last one being an `error`, so that the caller can know how to check for errors without having to read the documentation first. Maybe all negative return values are errors, or just `-1`. What happens if the library updates and adds another possible return value; do we get subtile bugs? Is 0 an error? `atoi` is a good example. In C, there's no way of knowing if it encountered an error (or if it just parsed the string "0"). In Go, it returns (int, error).

### if else if else if else if

The Go switch statement is very powerful and can be used instead of long if/elseif/elseif/else statements. If you omit the argument to `switch` it looks at the cases one by one until it finds one that is true, just like a long if/elseif/elseif statement does. In this case, however, since you need semicolons in your if-statements, switch does not work. Just a pointer for future code.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I appreciate it. The main points where I agree with you are doc conventions, unecessary exports, naming conventions, and the use of `gofmt` (although this code has already been run through `gofmt`).

Though the if-else chain is important to make sure production funcs are not run after a match has been found. Also, I've seen plenty of functions from the go standard library return -1 as a cardinal value when searching for indexes in array-like data structures, so I still prefer that approach to multiple return values. Thanks again.